Calculate the average rating of a stock portfolio



0
A
B
C




1
Stocks
Rating
Invested Value


2
Stock A
2
500


3
Stock B
3
800


4
Stock C
1
100


5
Stock D
3
900


6
Stock E
3
400


7





8
Average Rating
??



9






I have a portfolio of different stocks in Column A 
The stocks getting rated on a scale from 1-3. The rating of each stock you see in Column B. 
In Column C you can see the amount invested in each stock. 

Is there an Excel-Formula which can calculate the average rating of the portfolio in Cell B8?

If you want it to be weighted by the invested value:
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B6),(C2:C6))/SUM(C2:C6)
Explanation:
This effectively does, B2*C2 + B3*C3 + ... for each row and then divides by the combined invested value, giving you a weighted average.

Try this SUM(B2:B6) / COUNT(B2:B6) at cell B8
